# How to hook up activity to widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-activity

I made whit widget and it runs perfectly, button pressing works like a charm but i need to hook up activity to this widget. I need to call activity methods on these button events also. I searched many posts and everybody was making simple widgets just showing some text.

Activity needs to be started if such is not running and hooked to if such is already running.

Here is AppWidgetProvider class:

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.*;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MusicWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static final String PLAY_CLICKED = "MusicWidget.PLAY";
    private static final String PREV_CLICKED = "MusicWidget.PREV";
    private static final String NEXT_CLICKED = "MusicWidget.NEXT";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        ComponentName watchWidget;

        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
        watchWidget = new ComponentName(context, MusicWidget.class);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wbtnPlay,
                getPendingSelfIntent(context, PLAY_CLICKED));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wbtnPrevious,
                getPendingSelfIntent(context, PREV_CLICKED));
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wbtnNext,
                getPendingSelfIntent(context, NEXT_CLICKED));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(watchWidget, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        System.err.println("RECEIVE!");
        if (PLAY_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        } else if (PREV_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        } else if (NEXT_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        }
    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can communicate with your activity via an Intent sent from the widget:

```
// WidgetProvider.class

Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
launchIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
launchIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
launchIntent.putExtra("com.Company.App.LaunchWidget", true);    // an extra to tell your activity its being launced from the widget
.
. // set additional extras to pass data to your activity
.
context.startActivity(launchIntent);
```

The CATEGORY_LAUNCHER and ACTION_MAIN will ensure that your main activity is launched if not running.

In your activity, you'll receive the intent in onCreate (if activity needs to be created) or onNewIntent (if activity already running)

```
// YourActivity.class

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  .
  .
  .
  myIntentHandler(getIntent());
}

@Override 
void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
  myIntentHandler(intent);
}

void myIntentHandler(Intent intent)
{
 Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
 if ((extras != null) && (extras.getBoolean("com.Company.App.LaunchWidget") == true))
 {
  // this intent is from the widget
 }
}
```

Comment: So basicaly i need to recognize intents in this onNewIntent method in activity itself?

Comment: Yes, pass data via extras and do something in myIntentHandler, you can even start another activity in there if needed

Comment: I get Runtime exception, Unable to instantiate receiver MusicPlayerActivity, java.lang.ClassCastException, class can not be cast to BroadcastReceiver :P But i do not think its about your code, its just i don't know where to look for error.

Comment: Found error eventually, but whenever i press any button in widget activity takes over and its GUI launches over widget. Is there any way to run activity in background?

Comment: You've got the basic mechanics, but it sounds like you really want to be working with a SERVICE, not an ACTIVITY.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Every time i click any button in widget activity gets relaunched, is this code supposed to do that?

Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, MusicPlayerActivity.class);
launchIntent.putExtra(MusicPlayerActivity.PLAY, true);
context.startActivity(launchIntent);

in onReceive method in Widget. PLAY is string that Activity should recognize.

Comment: You should investigate your MusicPlayActivity android:launchMode setting in your manifest, set to "singleTask".  See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html for more info

Comment: Where should i call this starting activity code you provided in answer? It's being called every time i press button i found some errors in my ocde.